# How to split an array in many part and adding a new key (cakephp 2.5)

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

After research, I'm still looking for a solution.

I get this array in my controller, and I would like to separate as the result below. That's mean add one key with the uid reference.

Thanks

Original array:

```
array(
    'team_id-43' => '1',
    'view-43' => '1',
    'edit-43' => '1',
    'timesheet-43' => '1',
    'holiday-43' => '0',
    'author-43' => '12',
    'team_id-44' => '1',
    'view-44' => '0',
    'edit-44' => '1',
    'timesheet-44' => '0',
    'holiday-44' => '0',
    'author-44' => '12'
)
```

Result wanted:

```
$uid43 = array(
  'team_id' => '1',
  'user_id' => 43
  'view' => '1',
  'edit' => '1',
  'timesheet' => '1',
  'holiday' => '0',
  'author' => '43',
```

);

```
$uid44 = array(
 'team_id' => '1',
 'user_id' => 44
 'view' => '1',
 'edit' => '1',
 'timesheet' => '1',
 'holiday' => '0',
 'author' => '43',
```

);

Comment: How are you getting this array? Maybe we can help you quite a better query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will convert your array (called `$test` here) in the 2 arrays you want

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    $keyIndex = explode('-', $key);
    $keyIndex = $keyIndex[count($keyIndex) - 1];
    if (is_numeric($keyIndex)) {
        $newKey = str_replace('-' . $keyIndex, '', $key);
        $arrayName = 'uid' . $keyIndex;
        if (!isset($$arrayName)) {
            $$arrayName = array();
        }
        ${$arrayName}["$newKey"] = $value;
    }

}

print_r($uid43);
print_r($uid44);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, it's exactly what I wanted.
I need to analyse your code now to understand.
Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use `preg_match()`. Example:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    preg_match( '/-\d+/', $key, $matches);
    $ind = trim($matches[0], '-');
    if(is_numeric($ind)){
        $px = str_replace($matches[0], '', $key);
        $newArr['uid'.$ind][$px] = $val;
    }
}

extract($newArr, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

print '<pre>';
print_r($uid43);
print_r($uid44);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks too ;) I tried both function. Both are working very well ;)